# Making an instance of a private class in a public class in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I am looking to make an instance of Car in a constructor called VehiclePanel, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it, so here I am. Is anyone able to help with this?

```
public class VehiclePanel extends JPanel {
//variables here

public VehiclePanel() {
// somehow need to create a new instance of Car class and add it to the VehiclePanel


}


private class Car extends JPanel {
// Car code here, not important
}
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `Car car = new Car();` -- and then use your car variable? Your question confuses me as I have no idea what problems you're experiencing.

Comment: `this.add(new Car());`

Comment: If `Car` has no need to access the state of `VehiclePanel`, consider making it a [`static` nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public VehiclePanel() {
  Car car = new Car();
  add(car);
}
```

Note that since Car is declared inside VehiclePanel, the fact that it is private doesn't matter.